# C++11 universal initialization cause unexpected initialization?

Tags: c++, c++11

In C++ 11, The new universal initialization syntax can also be used to call a normal constructor (that doesn't take a initializer_list parameter). While by looking it is not bad, I think that could cause a problem in real world usage.

So suppose in my project I use a library that comes with the following class:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int size, int value); // create 'size' number of elements
    Foo(initializer_list<int> list);  // create elements as in 'list'
}
```

In the project it is used in this way:

```
Foo foo{10, 2};  // initialize foo with 2 elements: 10 and 2
```

Now the library got a new release and in the new release the author has removed the 2nd constructor that takes a initializer_list (either by purpose or by mistake). I didn't notice the change and my project builds happily as before, only with an unexpected foo being initialized (now it's 10 elements instead of 2).

A different version of this problem is that Foo had only the 1st constructor and you use the universal initialization syntax to init foo, and now the author has decided to add the 2nd constructor and that equally causes foo to be initialized with different elements without being noticed.

Just wanted to know other people's opinion about this. Is it a real problem or am I worrying too much? Is there any solution to prevent this from happening? Thanks.

Comment: It's certainly a good argument against regarding it as "universal", and trying to use it universally. Use the correct name, "list initialisation", and only use it when you specifically want to initialise from a list. Or when the syntax forces you to, e.g. in-class initialisation, or to avoid a vexing parse. (But that's just my opinion, not an answer, since there isn't really an answer.)

Comment: Scott Meyers covers this in Effective Modern C++ in item 7 very well and yes it is a real problem.

Comment: Very cool question. Can somebody explain why the parenthesis `()` are allowed to be skipped?

Comment: @Chiel Because it's list initialisation, that's the whole point.

Comment: Following @ShafikYaghmour: The gist is that the compiler will definitely prefer the initializer list construction when braces are used. std::vector has this exact problem, in fact. When constructors such as these are present, one must become very careful about using `()` versus `{}`

Comment: @Angew. I should have formulated it more clearly. Why is it decided to allow this? What is the purpose? In case the first on had to be initialized with `foo(10,2)` and the second with `foo({10,2})` there wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Chiel Yes. But list-initialisation allow you to do things like `return {4, 2};` instead of `return foo(4, 2);`. `{}` can only mean initialisation, so you don't have to specify the type. `()` can mean anything (for some values of "anything"). Not to mention the most vexing parse.

Comment: Would `explicit` be useful here?

Comment: @MikeSeymour  It avoids the most vexing parse for compilers because there's clearly a priority, but now we are vexed to parse these things!  I'd personally rather the compiler continue struggle and give me errors about declarations that I use as definitions; debugging run-time segfaults due to an ambiguous constructor call is far more time consuming than a compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

The real problem is that the API changed.

If the constructor was

```
Foo(int size, int value);
```

and you used

```
Foo foo(10, 2);
```

and the API would have been changed to

```
Foo(int value, int size);
```

you would have the same problem.

Comment: I feel they are different. In your example, the constructor has changed its parameters - clearly an incompatible API change. In my example, neither parameters nor implementations are changed for any existing constructors. Especially for adding a new function to a class, people would not expect the API has been changed in an incompatible way.

Comment: You can have the same problem without initializer in the same way, just make the original constructor `Foo(size_t size, int value)` and a new constructor `template <typename... Types> Foo(Types... values)`. When you called the original constructor with `Foo foo(10, 2)`, it would match the new constructor now.

Comment: Indeed, a template constructor can have the same effect. As commented above from  Chiel and  Aggieboy, if C++ explicitly reports ambiguities in these cases and requires, the problem can be avoided. But I guess that could lead to difficulties in using the class in a template.