# Is it good habit to always initialize objects with {}?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

Initializing objects with new {} syntax like this:

```
int a { 123 };
```

has benefit - you would not declare a function instead of creating a variable by mistake. I even heard that it should be habit to always do that. But see what could happen:

```
// I want to create vector with 5 ones in it:
std::vector<int> vi{ 5, 1 }; // ups we have vector with 5 and 1.
```

Is this good habit then? Is there a way to avoid such problems?

Comment: Yes because you disable narrowing conversions.

Comment: Wait, doesn't this have tons of duplicates?

Comment: Scott Meyers has an item dedicated to this in Modern Effective C++

Comment: @Columbo: At least some near-dupes anyway. E.g., http://stackoverflow.com/q/28366877/179910, http://stackoverflow.com/q/20603403/179910, for only a couple.

Comment: This question would probably be a better fit for Programmers.SE--and in fact it already has a reasonable dupe there: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/133688/89959

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Frankly, the subtleties of the various initialization techniques make it difficult to say that any one practice is a "good habit."

As mentioned in a comment, Scott Meyers discusses brace-initialization at length in *Modern Effective C++*. He has made further comments on the matter on his blog, for instance [here](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2015/02/why-auto-deduces-stdinitializerlist-for.html) and [here](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2015/09/thoughts-on-vagaries-of-c-initialization.html). In that second post, he finally says explicitly that he thinks the morass of C++ initialization vagaries is simply bad language design.

As mentioned in 101010's answer, there are benefits to brace-initialization. The prevention of implicit narrowing is the main benefit, in my opinion. The "most vexing parse" issue is of course a genuine benefit, but it's paltry--it seems to me that in most cases an incorrect `int a();` instead of `int a;` would probably be caught at compile time.

But there are at least two major drawbacks:

- In C++11 and C++14, `auto` always deduces `std::initializer_list` from a brace-initializer. In C++17, if there's only one element in the initialization list, and `=` is *not* used, `auto` deduces the type of that element; <s>the behavior for multiple elements is unchanged</s> (See the second blog post linked above for a clearer explanation, with examples.) (**Edit:** as pointed out by T.C. in a comment below, my understanding of the `C++17` rules for `auto` with brace initialization is *still* not quite right.) All of these behaviors are somewhat surprising and (in mine and Scott Meyers' opinions) annoying and perplexing.
- 101010's third listed benefit, which is that initialization list constructors are preferred to all other constructors, is actually a drawback as well as a benefit. You've already mentioned that the behavior of `std::vector<int> vi{ 5, 1 };` is surprising to people familiar with `vector`'s old two-element constructor. Scott Meyers lists some other examples in *Effective Modern C++*. Personally, I find this even worse than the `auto` deduction behavior (I generally only use `auto` with copy initialization, which makes the first issue fairly easy to avoid).

**EDIT:** It turns out that stupid compiler-implementation decisions can sometimes be [another reason to use brace-initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33681284/1858225) (though really the `#undef` approach is probably more correct).

Comment: `auto i{1,2};` is ill-formed in C++17, and that change is a DR, so you should see it in C++11/14 modes as well.

Comment: @T.C. DR meaning "defect report"? I'm not sure what that means--is it essentially a retroactive change to previous versions of the standard? If so, I didn't realize such a thing existed. Do you happen to know of a good write-up somewhere on the behavior of `auto` that includes that information? I'd rather link to some other resource than attempt a complete/correct explanation when my main point is just "it's complicated and confusing."

Answer (score 4):

Initializing objects with [list
    initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)
    should be preferred wherever applicable, because:

1. Among other benefits
   list-initialization limits the allowed implicit narrowing
   conversions.

   In particular it prohibits:

   - conversion from a floating-point type to an integer type
   - conversion from a `long double` to `double` or to `float` and conversion    from `double` to `float`, except where the source is a
     constant    expression and overflow does not occur.
   - conversion from an integer type to a floating-point type, except    where the source is a constant expression whose value can be stored 
     exactly in the target type.
   - conversion from integer or unscoped enumeration type to integer type    that cannot represent all values of the original, except
     where source    is a constant expression whose value can be stored
     exactly in the    target type.
2. Another benefit is that is immune to [most vexing
   parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).
3. Also, initialization list constructors are preferred over other
   available constructors, except for the default.
4. Also, they're widely available, all STL containers have initialization list constructors.

Now concerning your example, I would say with knowledge comes power. There's a specific constructor for making a vector of 5 ones (i.e., `std::vector<int> vi( 5, 1);`).

Comment: And it doesn't bother you that `std::vector<int> vi( 5, 1);` looks almost exactly like `std::vector<int> vi{ 5, 1};` but does something very different? There are enough pitfalls with brace-initialization that I think it's not helpful to list only its advantages.

Comment: @KyleStrand With a knife you can cut bread, you can also cut your fingers in the process, so learn how to properly use a knife. Every feature has its advantages and its disadvantages. IMHO using brace initialization has more advantages than disadvantages.

Comment: [Clearly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pWdd6_ZxX8c). But even if we take your analogy at face-value (and I'm not convinced any modern language should be as "knife-like" as C++ is, let alone as confusing--knives are simple!), in order to use a knife properly without hurting yourself, you must understand the risks as well as the benefits. Your answer explains only the benefits--and there are real risks.

Comment: And my comment about the two initializations *looking* very similar is more than just aesthetics. As Joel Spolsky says, [wrong code should look wrong](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html). If two pieces of code *look* very similar but *do* very different things, that's somewhat dangerous from a language design (and usage) perspective.

Comment: @KyleStrand the looks of something is in most cases subjective. For example is it good to use `new` when you have smart pointers?

Comment: IMHO the best rule of thumb is to never use braces when planning to call an actual constructor, excepting only the default constructor. Braces are good for primitives, default/value initialization, and list initialization. If you're calling a non-default constructor of a non-trivial type, use parentheses. (Edit: my sloppy "actual constructor" means "constructors that don't take an initialization list).

Comment: @101010 By "looks" I mean how the text of the code physically looks. It's not really "subjective" whether those two lines of code look similar; they do look similar. It is subjective whether or not that's a problem. As for `new`, you need to understand the dangers *as well as* the benefits in order to use it well--just as with brace initialization. (And no, I personally do not use `new` where I can avoid it with `make_unique`.)

Comment: By the way, here's an interesting (minor) benefit (in some cases): http://stackoverflow.com/a/33681284/1858225