# Uniform initialization causes runtime error in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, uniform-initialization

I'm huge fan of uniform initialization and I'm using it in most cases when i want to construct initialized variable. Recently, I came across weird error while i was constructing variable of type `cv::Mat`.

```
cv::Mat lookUpTable( 1, 256, CV_8U );
uchar* p = lookUpTable.ptr();

for( int i = 0; i < 256; ++i )
{
    p[i] = cv::saturate_cast<uchar>( pow( i / 255.0, gamma ) * 255.0 );
}
```

While this implementation works well, if uniform initialization is used

```
cv::Mat lookUpTable{ 1, 256, CV_8U };
```

following error shows up

> malloc_consolidate(): invalid chunk size

I'm still not really sure what happes. Is different constructor (than supposed) used ? Can somebody explain further, please ?

Comment: Looks like uniform initialization gives more harm than good

Comment: I wonder if after this you'll still consider yourself a fan of uniform initialization. :P

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33444814/is-it-good-habit-to-always-initialize-objects-with

Comment: @HolyBlackCat hope not so huge fan anymore

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`cv::Mat lookUpTable{ 1, 256, CV_8U }` calls a different constructor than `cv::Mat lookUpTable( 1, 256, CV_8U )`.  `cv::Mat lookUpTable{ 1, 256, CV_8U }` is *direct-list-initialization* and since `cv::Mat` has a constructor accepting a `std::initlizer_list`, that constructor will be called instead of the 3 parameter one the first call does.  This means you have a matrix that contains the elements `{ 1, 256, CV_8U }`, instead of a 256 element matrix.

Nicolai Josuttis has a really nice talk at CppCon2018  about the "uniformity" of uniform initialization: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs

Answer (score 6):

Using `{...}` to construct an object is called *"list-initialization"*.

`cv::Mat` provides a constructor taking `std::initializer_list`:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp#L1007

There is a [special rule](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match#list) in *overload resolution* that **always** gives priority to constructors taking `std::initializer_list` if *list-initialization* is used, regardless of the existence of other constructors which might require less implicit conversions.

Calling `cv::Mat(...)` is completely different from `cv::Mat{...}`.

---

My mental model for this is: if the object you're constructing is a container, then `{...}` will likely behave differently from `(...)`, therefore you should be careful. Otherwise, prefer `{...}`.